# React Native - Return value from event listener in a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, listener, es6-promise

This has more to do with promises and async/await than the package I am using but in any event, the package is [react-native-background-upload](https://github.com/Vydia/react-native-background-upload/) and I have an issue with getting back the response from inside of the 'completed' event listener. I think my understanding of how these promises resolve might be wanting but I need to return the response from the server after the upload is complete. The example file provided [here](https://github.com/Vydia/ReactNativeBackgroundUploadExample) mostly caters for logging to the console, not returning data from the server.

```
async submit() {
    const responsefromUpload = await this.videoUploader().then((data) => data);
    console.log(responsefromUpload);
}
```

from which I call the function below

```
videoUploader() {
  const { video } = this.state;
  video.uri = Platform.OS == 'android' ? video.uri.replace('file://', '') : video.uri;
  const options = {
    url: 'https://upload.wistia.com',
    path: video.uri,
    method: 'POST',
    field: 'file',
    type: 'multipart',
  };
  return Upload.startUpload(options).then((uploadId) => {
    console.log('Upload started');
    Upload.addListener('progress', uploadId, (data) => {
      console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`);
    });
    Upload.addListener('error', uploadId, (data) => {
      console.log(`Error: ${data.error}%`);
    });
    Upload.addListener('cancelled', uploadId, (data) => {
      console.log('Cancelled!');
    });
    Upload.addListener('completed', (data) => {
      // data includes responseCode: number and responseBody: Object
      console.log('Completed!');
      return data.resporesponseBody; // this return doesn't work
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Upload error!', err);
  });
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just move ```console.log(responseFromUpload)```, or whatever additional functionality you want to add in your submit function, into the handler for the completed event?

Comment: I wish I could but there's a ton of other uploads that need to be done as well. I'll consider it though.

Answer (score -1):

wrap the code in `.then((uploadId) => { ... }` in a "new Promise" - resolve the promise in `completed` handler ... `resolve(data.resporesponseBody);`

i.e.

```
videoUploader() {
    const {video} = this.state;
    video.uri = Platform.OS == 'android' ? video.uri.replace('file://', '') : video.uri;
    const options = {
        url: 'https://upload.wistia.com',
        path: video.uri,
        method: 'POST',
        field: 'file',
        type: 'multipart',
    };
    return Upload.startUpload(options)
    .then(uploadId => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Upload started');
        Upload.addListener('progress', uploadId, data => {
            console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`);
        });
        Upload.addListener('error', uploadId, data => {
            console.log(`Error: ${data.error}%`);
            reject(data);
        });
        Upload.addListener('cancelled', uploadId, data => {
            console.log('Cancelled!');
            reject(data); //?
        });
        Upload.addListener('completed', data => {
            // data includes responseCode: number and responseBody: Object
            console.log('Completed!');
            resolve(data.responseBody);
        });
    }))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Upload error!', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it out but unfortunately, the 'completed' listener doesn't return anything. I'm not sure if this is getting registered at all or if it's being ignored by the library. In any event, this came the closest to solving this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can the wrap startUpload .then block code inside a Promise and resolve it on the completion of file upload.

```js
function videoUploader() {
  const { video } = this.state;
  video.uri = Platform.OS == 'android' ? video.uri.replace('file://', '') : video.uri;
  const options = {
    url: 'https://upload.wistia.com',
    path: video.uri,
    method: 'POST',
    field: 'file',
    type: 'multipart'
  };

  return Upload.startUpload(options).then(uploadId => {
    const uploadCompletionPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Upload.addListener('progress', uploadId, data => {
        console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`);
      });
      Upload.addListener('error', uploadId, data => {
        console.log(`Error: ${data.error}%`);
      });
      Upload.addListener('cancelled', uploadId, data => {
        console.log('Cancelled!');
      });
      Upload.addListener('completed', data => {
        console.log('Completed!');
        resolve(data.resporesponseBody);
      });

    });
    return uploadCompletionPromise
     .then(response => ({ success: true, data: response }))
     .catch(error => ({ success: false, error }));
  }).catch((error) => {
     console.log('Upload error!', error);
     return { success: false, error } 
  });
}
```

Comment: curious. why the `return uploadCompletionPromise()....` code? since `uploadCompletionPromise` isn't a function, won't that break? it's also being referenced inside the definition of `uploadCompletionPromise` - that too will break

Comment: Thanks @Jaromanda X for pointing out. By mistake, i kept it inside the promise itself.

Comment: it's still NOT A FUNCTION